# Failed to convert parameter value from a string to a decimal vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

I have an application where in the textbox I insert a number and click on a button and it should add that value on a textbox that I've called "Balance". To make that happen I've used a query to sum the amount and display it where I want. But I at the moment I have some issues with casts.

This is the function that I am using to get the results and then make some if statements to validate it. I have this function on a class.

```
Public Function BalancoTotal()
    SqlCon = New SqlConnection
    SqlCon.ConnectionString = "........"
    Try
        SqlCon.Open()
        Query2 = "SELECT 
                CAST(SUM(amountTransaction) AS INT) 
                FROM Transactions"

        SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query2, SqlCon)
        SqlDR = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        If SqlDR.Read() Then
            Return SqlDR.GetDecimal(0)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        SqlCon.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

And then I've called this function on my main form like this

```
txtBalance.Text = callMethod.BalancoTotal()
```

In the load form I've used this to lines of code to format the textbox

```
txtBalance.Text = 0.00
txtBalance.Text = FormatCurrency(txtBalance.Text)
```

But this is giving me 2 erros:

> failed to convert parameter value from a string to a decimal

And

> specified cast is not valid

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't assign a number to a Text propery: txtBalance.Text = 0.00

Comment: If you turn on Option Strict other issues will be revealed.  It will turn runtime errors into compiler errors you can fix so this and other errors are much less likely to happen,

Comment: So I should delete that line of code? @cicciorocca

Comment: No, you have to cast the decimal to a string because the Property "Text" of the Textbox is a String Property.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes...Some ahahha

Comment: Your function does not return a value on all code paths, it is leaking, and apparently `amountTransaction` is a decimal and SQL cant cast to `Int` plus 2 other things I can see.  Not sure that is much to laugh at.

Comment: You should tells us the exact line of the error... It's very hard to help without knowing where the error is.

Comment: I have told you the error in the post @the_lotus

Comment: @IGottaGo You told the error but not the line of the error. You should pass a number to FormatCurrency, not a string. FormatCurrency(0.00). Also, if you format your textbox as currency, you can't use txtBalance.Text anymore as if it was a number, for example setting a sql parameter.

Comment: I've made some tests with breakpoint and I found that the erro could come from here `.Add("@balaTransacao", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txtBalance.Text.ToString` @the_lotus

Comment: If you have this dubt, did you tried to set it casting to Integer? .Add("@balaTransacao", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = cint(txtBalance.Text)

Comment: Strings are not programming duct tape.  `txtBalance.Text.ToString` is not a BigInt and `ToString()` is pointless on `.Text` which is already string.  Take 15 mins to learn about datatypes.

Comment: @IGottaGo you can't do that since your textbox now contains a string with a dollar sign, which can be easily converted to a number. you'll have to do it properly and store the balance total in a decimal variable and use that variable for all your business logic.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem thanks guys for your help. @the_lotus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
txtBalance.Text = callMethod.BalancoTotal().ToString()

txtBalance.Text = "0.00"
```

Event if it should cast it ...

For the other problem you should try:

```
.Add("@balaTransacao", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = cint(txtBalance.Text)
```

Comment: It still saying the same -.-

Comment: Which is the line that gives you the error?

Comment: I don't know if it is because of this line of code of SqlParameters: `                .Add("@balaTransacao", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txtBalance.Text
`

Comment: It says: The cast "0.00" to the "Integer" type is not valid.

Comment: .Add("@balaTransacao", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txtBalance.Text this line bro

Comment: Cast it to Integer as i have written above: .Add("@balaTransacao", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = cint(txtBalance.Text)

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with you problem...Thank you man